# Can haproxy use umlaut-domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, haproxy, idn

I am hosting several webpages on one server.

For Routing, I am using haproxy.

Now, one funny user wants an umlaut-domain "supportbär.de".

```
#haproxy.cfg

frontend http-in
  ..
  acl is_supportbaer hdr_dom(host) -i supportbär
  use_backend supportbaer_wp if is_supportbaer
```

Usually, this works. But in this case, backend "supportbaer_wp" is not used.

Can haproy handle umlaut-domains? How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing can handle umlaut domains - as domains can not have an umlaut.

The browser has to translate them to another form because the URL can not be transmitted in umlauts.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

has the algorithms.

This was done for compatibility.

So, HaProxy will not see the ae - it will see the coding according to IDN. Use that and it should work.

> Example of IDNA encoding[edit] IDNA encoding may be illustrated using
>   the example domain Bücher.ch. “Bücher” is German for “books”, and .ch
>   is the ccTLD of Switzerland. This domain name has two labels, Bücher
>   and ch. The second label is pure ASCII, and is left unchanged. The
>   first label is processed by Nameprep to give bücher, and then
>   converted to Punycode to result in bcher-kva. It is then prefixed with
>   xn-- to produce xn--bcher-kva. The resulting label suitable for use in
>   the DNS is therefore xn--bcher-kva.ch.

For conversions you can use an online IDN service, such as http://mct.verisign-grs.com/

Comment: Specifically, for your question, "supportbär.de" translates into "xn--supportbr-22a.de"

Comment: There is also [`idn`(1)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/manual/libidn.html#Invoking-idn)